# C# wpf Process.start won't work without a breakpoint

Tags: c#

Below is my code:

```
public static void ImageDoubleClick(FileModel file)
        {
            if (file == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(file.FileName)
            {
                UseShellExecute = true
            });
        }
```

When I double click the image it supposes to open the file with system shell. But when I double click. nothing happened as if I didn't trigger the event. But I knew it did.

So I added a breakpoint at "Process.Start" line.  It did stop.  Then if I click "Continue", the file will be opened properly.

What am I missing here? Thanks for your help.

the Code for the xaml is:

```
<ContentControl VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseDoubleClick]=[Action ImageDoubleClick($dataContext)]">
                                        <StackPanel x:Name="border"
                                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseLeftButtonUp]=[Action ImageClick($dataContext)]"
                                                Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <Border Height="25" Width="25">
                                                <StackPanel>
                                                    <Canvas Width="24" Height="24"
                                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                            >
                                                        <Canvas.Background>
                                                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding FileImage}" 
                                                                    AlignmentX="Center"
                                                                    AlignmentY="Center"
                                                                    Stretch="Fill" />
                                                        </Canvas.Background>
                                                        <CheckBox Name="myCheckBox" 
                                                                  IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"
                                                                  Visibility="Collapsed" />
                                                    </Canvas>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </Border>
                                            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                        Visibility="{Binding ImageTextEnabled, Converter={StaticResource VisibleIfTrueConverter}}"
                                                        >
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}"
                                                           FontFamily="Microsoft YaHei, Arial"
                                                           FontSize="7"
                                                           FontWeight="Bold"
                                                           Foreground="Black"
                                                           Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignOverlineTextBlock}"
                                                           TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                                                           HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                           Margin="5,0,0,0"
                                                           Width="200" />
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CreatedDateTime, Mode=OneWay,  StringFormat='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}"
                                                           FontFamily="Microsoft YaHei, Arial"
                                                           FontSize="7"
                                                           FontWeight="Bold"
                                                           Foreground="Gray"
                                                           Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignOverlineTextBlock}"
                                                           TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                                                           HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                           Margin="5,0,0,0"
                                                           Width="200" />
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </ContentControl>
```

And I just tried and figured out this code works just fine after compiling. It is only working weird in visual studio 2019 debugging mode.  No clue what's wrong.

Comment: Where is your event ?

Comment: Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it won't be possible to provide a good answer. That said, _most likely_ the image file you're trying to open is one you're creating in the program itself, and you've failed to completely close the file and release its file handles before you try to open it via `Process`. So when the shell tries to open the file on behalf of `Process`, it fails because the file is locked. When you debug, you slow things down enough that it works. If you think the problem is something else, please improve the post. See also [ask].

Comment: @Clint, it is MVVM, this is the event.

Comment: @Peter Duniho. It won't be locked. Because I don't open the file before this step. The image just an image representing the file.

Comment: Then fix your question so it includes a proper [mcve]. There's no way to explain the behavior you describe, as it stands now.

Comment: @Peter Duniho, I have added some Xaml Code.  But I don't think they are related.  It is clear enough.  It is a weird question to me. I don't know how to duplicate it.

Comment: _"It is clear enough"_ -- no, it's not. All due respect, the person who asks the question does not get to decide whether the question is "clear enough".  If you want an answer, you need to improve the question, by providing a good [mcve] others can use to a) know exactly what your code is doing, and b) reproduce it themselves so that they can debug the issue.

Answer (score -1):

**(Not answer but alternative)**

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(file.FileName);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have to add "UseShellExecute" to my process.

Comment: try like this, myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                   
                    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName =file.FileName;
                    myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    myProcess.Start();

Comment: check if FileName is invalid

Comment: No. If the FileName is null it will return. if invalid will be an exception. And it did work after the stop.

Comment: shell has problems so I prefer direct passing to CMD

Comment: check file.FileName, is it valid path, try the path in D: drive because manytimes C: drive has permission issues